Is it possible to make .NET 4.8.1 support HTTP/2 using OWIN?
I want to enable HTTP/2 protocol with OWIN in ASP.NET webforms project. I have created a simple webforms project and added OWIN Startup class to this project like this:
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(PageParser.Startup))]
namespace PageParser
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next.Invoke();
            });;
        }
    }
}

How can I change this code to support Http/2 ?
Is it possible to use WinHttpHandler for enabling HTTP/2 in this project?
At the end how can we test this project to see if HTTP/2 is active?

IIS10 and later Support HTTP/2 by default
Checking HTTP response headers in a browser tool (like Chrome DevTools).
Looking for the "h2" protocol in the Network tab.

does this code support http/2 ?

The code you provided does not inherently determine whether HTTP/2 is used or not. HTTP/2 support is handled at the web server level (such as IIS) and depends on the protocol negotiation between the client (e.g., browser) and the server.

https://github.com/owin/owin/issues/49

What if I use the package WinHttpHandler in OWIN? This package has the property EnableMultipleHttp2Connections. I want to config my ASP.NET Web Forms project to work on HTTP/2.0 with these tools.
